# Saving and hiding data in android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i am creating app which would download and save files, than user could use them not being online. So i need place where i could save for example music downloaded from web.

User could listen to it, but user can't get that music.
I need place where i could store that files which user wouldn't see.

Maybe someone can help me how can i do this ? 
Also i need place to save my sqlite database.

Thanks.

P.S. i am also now searching examples how could i call setSomething to Activity class before i call that activity.

Now i am calling like this:

```
Thread my_files_thread = new Thread(){

    //start thread
    public void run (){
        try{

            startActivity(new Intent("android.app.reader.FILES"));

        }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

                //finish();
            }
    }

};// Brackets means that thread is closing
```

Comment: Simeple Answer, just store them on SD Card

Comment: There is no way that user could find that files when he connects SD Card to computer ?

Comment: If you store your data without declaring a specific path, the direcotory of the app is choosen automatically. in non rooted devices is this directory hidden. You can't avoid that users will be able to access the files on rooted devices, than you should think about encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your activity use this to save:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("file.mp3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(...) // etc
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then use this to open:

```
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("file.mp3");
```

Files will only be visible to your app then and you won't be clogging up the SD card with clutter. When the user goes to your app settings and presses "Clear app Data" your files will be lost however.

Hope this helps

Comment: but keep in mind, this is one of the cases where files will be accessable on rooted devices

Comment: Indeed, if someone roots their device they can pretty much do what they want and access what they want.